# text-underline decoration not apply on all child element

Tags: html, css, text-decorations

I have a label "Show more", that display hidden content. I want all child element of this label to be underline including the arrow. The problem is that only the text has text-decoration and not the arrow. How can I solve this issue in order that also arrow will be in the same underline text.

Thanks

```css
#arrow_create {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.icos-angle-up {
  margin-left: 3px !important;
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
}

.icos-angle-down {
  margin: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}

.icos-angle-up {
  visibility: hidden;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked+label[for="read_more_checkbox"]>.icos-angle-up {
  visibility: visible;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked+label[for="read_more_checkbox"]>.icos-angle-down {
  display: none;
}

.read_more_txt {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox {
  display: none;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_txt {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.read_more_label {
  margin-left: 5px !important;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#read_more_checkbox~.read_more_label:before {
  content: attr(read_more);
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 4px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 110px;
}

#read_more_checkbox:checked~.read_more_label::before {
  text-decoration: underline;
  text-underline-offset: 4px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 1px;
  content: attr(read_less);
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label for="read_more_checkbox" class="read_more_label" read_more="Show more" read_less="Show less">
    <span id="arrow_create" class="icos-angle-down"></span>
    <span id="arrow_create" class="icos-angle-up"></span>               
    </label>
```

[image: What I have now]

[image: What I want]

Comment: you can change a way to think this problem, cause it named `text-decoration`, so it can only apply to text. another to approach the result you want is use CSS property `border-bottom` on the box which container the text and `span`

Comment: Thanks, this solve the problem. Perhaps, write it as an answer so that I can accept it.

Comment: You cannot have more than one element with `id="arrow_create"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So instead of using `text-decoration` (which only applies to text) you can either use `border-bottom` or to keep it more complicated there is also the possibility of using a css pseudo class.

##### Using border bottom

```css
.read_more_label {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

#arrow_create {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.icos-angle-down {
  margin: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<label class="read_more_label">
  Show more
  <span id="arrow_create" class="icos-angle-down"></span>           
</label>
```

##### Using css pseudo classes

The benefit of using pseudo classes would be that you also have the chance to design it more and you can even add some litte animations (as I did in the example)

```css
.read_more_label {
  position: relative;
}

.read_more_label::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

.read_more_label:hover::after {
  opacity: 1;
}

#arrow_create {
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
}

.icos-angle-down {
  margin: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<p>HOVER IT: </p>

<label class="read_more_label">
  Show more
  <span id="arrow_create" class="icos-angle-down"></span>           
</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If shape arrow doesn't matter.

```css
span {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <span>SHOW MORE &#8744;</span>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can use also other [HTML Special Characters](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/named-characters.html)

Another way

```css
span {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

span::after {
  content: "";
  border: solid black;
  border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
  margin: 3px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <span>SHOW MORE</span>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use hr tag to draw a line under any thing and then you can add css on hr according to your need.for example if you want to change color of that line you can simply add css on hr tag and change color.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).